# Problem with glossary text and accented letters

Tags: glossaries, accents

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with the *glossaries* package, I have these lines in the header of my document:

```
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
...
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
...
\makeglossaries
```

Then, in the text I have items such as

```
\gls{stivare}
```

And if I write in the glossary the "stivare" item this way:

```
\newglossaryentry{stivare}
{
  name=stivare,
  description={Mettere in  stiva. ... è sempre stato uno dei fattori più ...}
}
```

I.e., using "è" and "ù" letters, I get a compile error:

```
) (./FameInAltoMare.gls [26]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 ...entrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{11}}}
                                                  %
?
```

While if I write the same item using the "`e" and "`u" the compilation ends successfully.

Any clues?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome! Hard to say without a complete minimal example we can compile to reproduce the error. But do you have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`? If you are using LaTeX or pdfLaTeX (rather than one of the newer engines), you should.

Comment: yes, sorry, I forgot a snippet, I have \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} (instead of utf8) but not the fontenc, could it be those lines? I'll have a go and let you know, thank you

and I compile with pdflatex+bibtex+makeglossaries

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to inconsistent file encodings.

Answer (score 1):

It was my fault, I have various files, they were formatted differently: part UTF-8 (the glossary) and part ISO-8859.. (checked with the 'file' command)

Now I 'recode'(d) all to UTF-8, edited the \inputenc command to UTF-8 and now it works everything (except for the .bib file)

Comment: Glad you sorted it!